# Save transparent image

Tags: python, opencv

I have a signature image like this:
[image]

I use OpenCV to save the image after preprocessing it.

```
cv2.imwrite('image.jpg', image)
```

How to save the transparent image of this? I want to keep the signature only. I have searched for it on google but I can't find the answer that I need.

Comment: jpg cant have transparency

Comment: Save as PNG or TIFF. JPG does not support transparency. Or change the transparency to some non-transparent color and then save as JPG

Comment: @JoranBeasley so if I save as .svg file, is there a way to get the transparent image?

Comment: SVG is a vector format, though it can contain an image. I would not recommend using SVG as output. Not sure that Python/OpenCV can write to that format!